# django - python 3.8 any url obfuscate packages available?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-urls, python-3.8

Working with django and Python 3.8 for url obfuscation, however no python packages available for the same.

The following py packages are not supported by python 3.8:

```
   url-obfuscate
   # link: https://pypi.org/project/url-obfuscate/

   django-unfriendly
   # link: django-unfriendly
```

Please suggest any url obfuscation packages.

Comment: Did you try? `django-unfriendly` is declared for 3.5, but I am not aware of any backwards-incompatible changes between 3.5 and 3.8...

Comment: I'm sure they would work with Python 3.8, but Django 3.x compatibility might be harder to attain.

Comment: Yes I did try pip installation, but facing error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required

Comment: That error has nothing to do with Python 3.8. It says that you must install VC++ 14.